Torque equilibrium problem

We have a stick which is connected to the wall with a rope, like shown in the picture. I need to set the resulting torque to $0$, since it's in equilibrium.
The solution in the textbook says:

Pick a pivot point where the string is attached to the stick. Then:
$$\frac{mgL}{2}\sin45^\circ = F_nL\cos45^\circ$$

I don't understand the right side of the equation. In my previous question on this forum, I asked about the force a wall can exert on an object like this one, and I was told that, if there is no friction, the wall can only exert a force perpendicular to itself (the force $F_n$). In other words, there should be no $y$ component to the force.
Though in this case, there seems to be a force $F_n\cos45^\circ$ perpendicular to the stick. Where does this come from, and isn't it at odds with the example I made in my previous post?

I just realized I did the exact same thing in my previous example, I just didn't notice it. How come that there is no y component to the Fn force when I'm summing up the y forces to 0, but when I'm doing that with torques, there is another component (Fncos45), which seems to have a y and x direction?

I think I figured it out. The Fn force can be broken down so that Fn is the x component, Fncos45 is the perpendicular force, and Fnsin45 is the y component. That doesn't mean that the wall actually exerts a force perpendicular to the desk in the same way, that breaking down mg to mgsin45 and mgcos45 doesn't mean that there is an actual force exerted perpendicular to the stick in the other direction. It's just a component of the mg force, which is the only force acting (directly downards), in the same way that Fncos45 is only a component of the only force acting perpendicular to the wall (fn)

Is my understanding correct?

This isn't asking to work out a homework-like problem, nor is it asking for work to be checked. Voting to reopen

You seem to think that because there's no vertical component to the force from the wall, it can't cancel out the torque from the weight (which is vertically directed.)  This is incorrect.  It's important to remember that this equation is a torque equation, and that both "horizontal" and "vertical" forces can contribute to the torque on an object.  For example, if I open a door 45°, I can cause it to rotate around its hinges either by applying a force parallel to the wall, or perpendicular to wall;  the door rotates equally well either way.
In this case, there are two torques exerted about the end of the stick.

The weight exerts a clockwise torque.  The force is $mg$ and the lever arm is $(L/2) \sin 45^\circ$, so the magnitude of the torque is $\frac12 mgL\sin45^\circ$.
The wall exerts a counter-clockwise torque.  The force is $F_n$ and the lever arm is $L \cos 45^\circ$.  So the torque is $F_n L \cos 45^\circ$.

These two torques must be equal if the object is in static equilibrium, which leads to the equal you found in your textbook.
I can't understand your additional reasoning in the comment, but I don't think it's correct.  The wall really does exert a horizontal force on the stick of magnitude $F_n$, and any line of reasoning that leads you away from that is not a valid one.

To correct a misconception from the comments:  The torque doesn't have $x$- and $y$-components.  For the purposes of a 2D problem like this one, you can just think of it as a scalar, where "positive" means "counter-clockwise" and "negative" means "clockwise."  Any force that would cause the object to rotate counter-clockwise, regardless of the direction of the force, contributes a positive torque.  Similarly, any force that would cause the object to rotate clockwise counts as negative.
To avoid pedantry in the comments, I'll add the following:  At a more sophisticated level (when dealing with fully 3D problems), torque does have to be thought of as a vector.  But its direction is determined by the right-hand rule, and in particular the torque vector is perpendicular to both the force vector and the radial vector (the vector from the origin to the point of application.)  In this picture, if a force and its radial vector are both in the $xy$-plane, then the resulting torque points along the $z$-axis.  The description above concerning "positive" and "negative" torques is then really just a statement about the sign of the $z$-component of the torque vector.

Let's say that we need to draw all of the forces. I would draw mg, and then break it into mgsin45 and mgsin45. mg is a force in the y direction, and the mgcos45 is the force in the x direction. then I would break the force Fn (x direction) into Fncos45 and Fnsin45(y direction). Why don't I take the Fnsin45 into account when summing up all the forces in the y direction to 0 (for equilibrium)? How come the Fncos45 is relevant, and Fnsin45 isn't? Sorry for the basic questions, but I'm self studying and really want to understand.

In other words, doesn’t Fncos45 imply Fnsin45?

not if Fn is the force the wall does.

So if Fncos45 would be the force the wall does, then it could be broken into Fn and Fnsin45, but since Fn is the source, I cannot do that? What’s the technical explanation for this, just so I know when to avoid this mistake

Little bit of a subtle point.  When objects have "frictionless contact" then it's true that the force can only be in the perpendicular direction.  Another way to say this is that if there was relative sliding, the contact force can do no work (i.e. can't dissipate energy).   BUT, although it's not the case here, many times there is a frictionless hinge or pivot at the end of the stick.  In those cases there CAN be reaction forces on both axes.  So you may see a similar problem to this one but with a hinge which does include  Fx and Fy.

@Mixoftwo Which way are you defining the $x$ and $y$ directions?  If $x$ is horizontal and $y$ is vertical, then the weight has 0 component in the $x$-direction, and the force from the wall has 0 component in the $y$-direction. More generally, it should always be the case that any vector is equal to the sum of its $x$- and $y$-components (viewed as vectors, and taking the vector sum.)  Respectfully, I would recommend that you review how vector addition and components work; you seem kind of confused about this point, and what you've written doesn't make a lot of sense.

I see that Fn has no y component. That’s why I’m wondering where Fncos45 comes from, since this one has got a y component. If I were to break down Fncos45 into x and y components, what would that look like?

I’m just confused how Fn can affect the y component of the torque. Intuitively it makes sense, but I seem to misunderstand physics, since I can’t make sense of it theoretically for some reason.

@Mixoftwo:  See my addendum to the answer above.

I think I get it. Is this problem equivalent to pushing at a door at a 45 degree angle? If so, then this was one massive brainfart

Thanks. I need to review forces :/ This textbook covers statics before dynamics and newton laws, so I’m just going based off intuition. For some reason I confused Fncos45 for the acting force (force exerted by the wall) while Fn is the actual acting force and Fncos45 is just a component of it acting on the ladder right?

Geometrically to have torque balance, all three forces need to meet at some point

To have force balance, the three forces when slid to this point must balance out according to the trapezoidal rule

As you can see the net torque about this point (indicated as a black dot) is zero since all the force lines go through it.
To solve this problem use geometry to find the location of this point, which will give you the orientation of the tension load $F_t$.
